# What does the imports node in Visual Studio ASP.NET Core project represent?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Anyone know what this node represents? It is different from Dependencies which and I think it appeared after a recent update. In addition it seems strange and somewhat useless that it shows a bunch of identically named nodes unless I drill down.

[image: Imports Node in Visual Studio]